# Restrict edge set to certain nodes only

Tags: graph-theory, article-writing

Given a graph $G=(V,E \subseteq V \times V)$, an edge set $D \subseteq E$ and a subset of nodes $W \subseteq V$, is there such thing as an established operator for the "restricted" set of $D$:

$$
\{ (u,v) | u \in W \vee v \in W\} \subseteq D
$$

I did not find anything at wikipedia, but that does not necessarily mean something.

In case there is no such established operator, is $D | W$ acceptable/readable (i.e. has it some other obvious meaning in graph theory that I am not aware of?)

Comment: $D|W$ is sometimes used as shorthand for $W$ having a decomposition into subgraphs isomorphic to $D$; akin to "$D$ divides $W$".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of any established notation for this, however, the notion of *incidence* is usually understood in a more general sense, that is, not only with regard to vertices/edges, but whole sets. Therefore, you could say that

$$\{(u,v) \in E \mid u∈W \lor v∈W\} \text{ is the subset of edges incident to }W.$$

Also, there is another similar notion, namely, the induced subgraph, i.e.

$$\{(u,v) \in E\mid u∈W \land v∈W\} \text{ is the set of edges induced by }W.$$

Given the two above, you can add that you intersect it with $D$. With some stretch, you can use function restriction notation $f|_\Omega$ (I have seen it used for induced subgraphs), but in any case, I would simply define the necessary operators, just to be clear (notation in graph theory varies a lot).

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$